# How can calculate conditional pdf of Y when you dont know about f(y)

Tags: conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

X is a uniform distribution on the interval (0,1). Y is a also uniform distribution on the interval (0,x). Its the only information that I could know. Then how can I calculate p(Y|x)? If you teach me, I will really appreciate that. Thanks for reading! Have a good day.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You are given that $Y\mid X$ is uniform on $(0,X)$.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand. Why Y|x have (0,x)? isnt for Y pdf? Im so sorry that I cant know that. Thank you for your kindness. Can u explain for me plz?

Comment: It is implied that they are talking about $Y$ given that $X=x$, when they say $Y\sim U(0,x)$.

Answer (score 0):

As the distribution of $Y$ is uniform, but dependent on $X$, the uniform PDF of $Y$ is actually $f_{Y|X} = \frac{1}{x}$ (as it is dependent on $X$).

Thus, $P(Y<y|X=x) = \int_0^y f_{Y|X}dy = \frac{y}{x}$

Comment: I really want to thank you for your help! Thank you for spending your time for me. Have a nice day!